# How do i add a new column to new .xlsx file when i combine 2 of them

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Priority : I would like to create a new column when i combine 2 .xlsx files, im pretty new to python, please help.

Secondly : i would also like to know how can i loop through the file in a folder? i am doing this hard coded but i would like to improve and loops thru every .xlsx files to create the result i want.

i tried to look for resources online, but couldnt find any

```
excel1 = '1.xlsx'
excel2 = '2.xlsx'
excel3 = '3.xlsx'

df1 = pd.read_excel(excel1)
df2 = pd.read_excel(excel2)
df3 = pd.read_excel(excel3)

values1 = df1[['Purchasing Document','Material','Quantity 
Received','Still to be delivered (qty)','invoice','cancel']]
values2 = df2[['Purchasing Document','Material','Quantity 
Received','Still to be delivered (qty)','invoice','cancel']]
values3 = df3[['Purchasing Document','Material','Quantity 
Received','Still to be delivered (qty)','invoice','cancel']]
dataframes = [values1, values2, values3]

join = pd.concat(dataframes)
join.to_excel("testing123.xlsx")
```

Actual result right now is only showing 4 columns, Purchasing document to Qty, invoice and cancel gives me error.
I expect the result to be showing 6 columns, 4 of them filled with documents and invoice and cancel will be blank.

Comment: Does all your excel file contain all 6 columns ? Or some files are missing a few columns ?

Comment: @SpandanBrahmbhatt the first 2 have the same columns, but the 3rd one have different columns from 1&2

Comment: Can you share the output of `df3.columns` ?

Comment: @SpandanBrahmbhatt None of [Index(['Purchasing Document',.....] are in the [columns] I actually ran into the same type of error at invoice and cancel for the first 2 excel.

Comment: Why don't you send the output of following - ```df3 = pd.read_excel(excel3); print(df3.columns)```

Comment: error, because there are no such columns name in excel3

Comment: Did you try running only the 2 lines I mentioned ? Just run the above two lines and not the ones that you have in your question.

Comment: yes this is the error.values3 = df3[['Purchasing Document', 'Material', 'Quantity Received', 'Still to be delivered (qty)']]KeyError: "None of [Index(['Purchasing Document', 'Material', 'Quantity Received',\n       'Still to be delivered (qty)'],\n      dtype='object')] are in the [columns]"

Comment: Please do not run the line `values3 = ...`.  First run the following line - `df3 = pd.read_excel(excel3)`. Next run `print(df3.columns)` and that's it. Send in the output.

Comment: Index(['PO', 'PO CHECK', 'Order', 'Part Number', 'Held', 'pendRlse',
       'backOrder', 'pendSrcd', 'rlsd', 'invoice', 'cancel', 'grf', 'futsrcd'],
      dtype='object') <<<< this is the output

Comment: Can you also similarly do - `df2 = pd.read_excel(excel2)`. Next run `print(df2.columns)` and send the output ?

Comment: Index(['Purchasing Document', 'Plant', 'Customer Reference Number', 'Item',
       'Material', 'Order Quantity', 'Vendor/supplying plant',
       'Storage Location', 'Order Unit', 'PO history/release documentation',
       'Req. Tracking Number', 'Release status', 'Deletion Indicator',
       'Quantity Received', 'Actual GR Quantity',
       'Still to be delivered (qty)'],
      dtype='object') << same result for 1 and 2

Answer (score 0):

For reading mutiple files from a folder and storing there data in a excel with multiple sheets, you can try below code :

```
import os
import pandas as pd
dirpath = "C:\\Users\\Path\\TO\\Your XLS folder\\data\\"
fileNames = os.listdir(dirpath)

writer = pd.ExcelWriter(dirpath+'combined.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
for fname in fileNames:
    df = pd.read_excel(dirpath+fname)
    print(df)
    df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=fname)    
writer.save()
```

i hope this would help in your second point.